# How to remove a div from a page so that it doesn't come back even after refreshing the page using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have created an HTML page which consists a form. Whenever a user closes this form ,it fades away. Now what I want to do is to remove this form so that it doesn't come even after refreshing the page. Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: You have two options: 1) using a server-side language, set a cookie, then show only when no cookie is set. 2) using localStorage (JavaScript only) https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, but you can try this:

1. `display: none` on the form in the html (a flexible way is to use a css class for this).
2. When someone triggers the form, you remove the `display: none` so it becomes visible.
3. When a user closes the form again you add the `display: none` class again.

This is ofcourse a solution that is independent of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Using only JavaScript & JQuery it is impossible, the only way you could manage to do that is to save a `cookie` or a key in your `localStorage` and use it when the page load to show/hide your form with some CSS.

However, in terms of security it is not advised since your users could just show your form and still use it by removing its `localStorage` key, `cookie` or modifying the CSS style to show it up.

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret your vague question, I believe this can help you...

As an example:

```
<form id="frm">
....
</form>
<button id="btnCloseForm"></button>
```

You can achieve this using JQuery:

```
//create cookie when clicked
$("#btnCloseForm").click(function() {
    createCookie("frmclosed","true",10);
});

//if cookie exists, remove form
if (readCookie("frmclosed") != null)
    $("#frm").remove();

   // Cookies
    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";               

        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is when you remove the form. Then store the form Id in **local storage** or **session storage**  as sessionStorage.setItem("somekey", formId), when ever page is refreshed if the key is present in session storage add display:none to the form.